# P&T Field Pack 2.1.1 on EE2.8.1 Installation Errors Notice and warnings

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack, install

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: enabled_types
Filename: fieldpack/helper.php
Line Number: 78

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: fieldpack/helper.php
Line Number: 78

On specific field types this error occurs. I am guessing that it is the foreach loop as it is only list, multiselect, pill, etc, fieldtypes.

Not stopping my development - but thought i should flag it and see if anyone knows reason / fix...

N

Answer (score 1):

P&T field pack has been superseded by fieldpack http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack. 
P&T field pack wont be supported by 2.8.1 but the upgrade to field pack is really simple do.

Comment: It looks like that's what the OP is already using.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the P&T field pack is not yet compatible with EE 2.8.x