# P&T Field Pack 2.1.1 on EE2.8.1: error on specific Checkbox field only

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack, checkbox, pt-checkboxes

I've read [P&T Field Pack 2.1.1 on EE2.8.1 Installation Errors Notice and warnings](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20543/pt-field-pack-2-1-1-on-ee2-8-1-installation-errors-notice-and-warnings) so I'm aware of that.

What I have is several Field Pack **Checkbox** fields across more than one site in an MSM installation, all of which seem to be behaving just fine: both in terms of output and field settings editability, except for one…

**One field only** is generating wrong output, and PHP errors if I try to edit the field.

```
Message: Undefined index: field_fmt_options
Filename: fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php
--
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
```

Which seems odd. Can't see anything in the DB so far to hint at why. It would make more sense to me if **all** the PT checkbox fields were issuing the same errors.

Anyway, I guess P&T FieldPack is dying a slow death? What alternatives do people recommend?

Answer (score 0):

That’s an EE core file, not a Field Pack file. Try updating EE and see if that helps. If not, please get in touch with us at support@pixelandtonic.com and we can try to look into it from there.